# Neo4j json dl import

Tags: neo4j

I'm just getting into Neo4j and I spent a couple hours mapping out some nodes and relationships.

I D/L'd the JSON and I'm trying to move the nodes to another computer, it seems like it should be a pretty simple query, but everything I'm finding about batch import is for csv's and a bit more involved.

Is the just a simple cypher to import the JSON d'l from the local Neo4j server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving a full graph db to another box is most simply done by copying over the `data/graph.db` directory.

Alternatively you can use `neo4j-shell`'s [`dump`](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_a_cypher_result_to_cypher_statements) command.